# If statement oddly not working properly...can't figure it out

Tags: java

So this is a silly question but for some reason this isn't working for me. This is a small part of a little program I am trying to do and I am debugging but a simple if statement isn't working for some reason. Here is the following code:

```
System.out.println("Enter a command (Enqueue, Dequeue, or Quit): ");
String expr = input.next();
System.out.println(expr);
if (expr=="Enqueue") {
   System.out.println("Enqueue");}
```

So it should simply grab the input, and if I type Enqueue into the prompt it should print it out. The problem is that it isn't doing it. When I check the value of the variable expr it does show up as the string Enqueue but it doesn't go in and print it.....odd. Is there something dumb I am missing?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
if (expr.equals("Enqueue")) {
```

`==` is not safe to use with Strings.  That operator compares the two *references* for equality, which will only be true when the two references point to the same *instance*.  In this case, you have two different instances that have the same *value*.  To do value comparisons, we use `.equals()`.

Comment: Yes from what little I've seen from the official Java tutorials they don't do a good job of warning you about this.